# convert html to js to html element

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a div element with the following js code, however the content (blog post, could contain html tag like `<br>` or `<bold>` etc.) What should I add to make sure that they are part of the formatting, instead of just being displayed as they are?

```
var blogcontent = document.createElement("div");
var mes = data[i].blogcontent ;
blogcontent.className = "blogContentClass";
blogcontent.appendChild(document.createTextNode(mes));
li.appendChild(blogcontent);
```

Comment: `blogcontent.innerHTML = mes` should do the trick.

Comment: `blogcontent.innerHTML += mes` instead of `blogcontent.appendChild(document.createTextNode(mes));`

Comment: Actually can someone explain why I have to do creatTextNode in some case and why I can also just .innerhtml in another? I don't understand the difference. Thanks!

Comment: Setting `innerHTML` replaces all existing content within an element (no matter if you you'd use `+=`). This might cause unexpected results/behavior when used on an existing element. `appendChild` doesn't change existing content.

Comment: [An example](http://jsfiddle.net/8fzcLnve/) how you can accidentally remove an event handler from a button using `innerHTML`.